# How to get correct QString from "\u0000"?

Tags: qt, unicode, qstring

Sometimes I receive QString with value "\u0000" and I want to check if the received string equals to "\u0000".
But when I try:

```
qDebug() << QString("\u0000") << QString::fromUtf8("\u0000");
```

I get output: `"\u0001"` `"\u0001"`

So as a result I can not compare the strings. I see that initially this string was created using `snprintf` from byte to get char* and then created std::string and QString from std::string, but I can't reproduce it so far actually. But I feel like this is a workaround, but not the easy way to do it.

How do I create QString with value `\u0000` using QString API and why `QString("\u0000")` results in value "\u0001"?

Comment: `\u0000` is the null character. What do you expect to be printed? If you want to check whether a string is null string, `QString::isNull()` might help.

Comment: @vahancho right, that is null. But I have actually "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000" string received, so I don't think I can just check it for NULL. Though I ll try.

Comment: The received QString "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000" returns `false` for `isNull()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to create such a string.

```
QString str(1, QChar('\0'));
```

or from std::string:

```
QString::fromStdString(std::string("\0", 1));
```

But I still don't know why `QString("\u0000")` results in "\u0001"

Answer (score 0):

QString is always null-terminated. A *null* QString means that it has no data in its internal array but an *empty* QString has a single null character in its internal data array. So, if you have any control over the sender of the original array, it is better to send it by a QByteArray instead of a QString. You won't be able to count multiple null characters in a QString.

From [QString](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qstring.html#distinction-between-null-and-empty-strings) reference document:

```
QString().isNull();               // returns true
QString().isEmpty();              // returns true

QString("").isNull();             // returns false
QString("").isEmpty();            // returns true

QString("abc").isNull();          // returns false
QString("abc").isEmpty();         // returns false
```

Comment: as I receive such a string, it is possible to create it. If it is possible to create it, it must be possible for me to create the same one to be able to compare them.

Comment: please send me the returning value of .length() of the QString with "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000" content.

Comment: The length of QString with "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000" is 4

Comment: @rightaway717 is that what you get from debugging console or is that your assumption?

Comment: that is output of length() method in console. Thank you, anyways, I figured out how t create this string and will post an answer